# setRetainInstance и вложеные фрагменты

Tags: android, android-fragment, fragment-transaction

Есть ViewPager, в одном из табов есть базовый фрагмент, который при инициализации вместо себя подключает (замещает себя) еще один фрагмент.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Init new fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_tab1, SearchFragment.newInstance(), getString(R.string.tag_tab_network));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
    else {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Saved instance: " + savedInstanceState.toString());
    }
}
```

Если я базовому фрагменту задаю

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

то при смене ориентации дочерний фрагмент не отрисовывается, а остается разметка базового фрагмента.

если же

```
setRetainInstance(false);
```

то все отрисовывается нормально (подключается дочерний фрагмент)

Вопрос: почему так происходит?
По идее надо в таких случаях самому восстанавливать фрагменты, но как ?